# magento how to add Recurring Profile and simple product to cart

Tags: magento

first i have to add simple product to cart but its doesn’t go to shopping cart page . it should be redirect to a category page . then in the category page i have to add a recurring profile to cart .

i didn’t know how to redirect to category page and i cant add this two products(recurring profile and simple product) to cart.
i cant add more than one product in cart .

any one having solution for this . . .
please help me
i am a new one to magento
pls replay me as soon as possible with correct solution

Answer (score 1):

Recurring products are "nominal items" in Magento which have several restrictions and qualities. One of the main restrictions is the inability to add more than one item to your cart. From the official Magento site:

> Currently no more than one nominal item can be added to the shopping cart at a time. A nominal item and a regular item cannot be added to the shopping cart simultaneously. This happens because of the current order submission rules – while an order in Magento is submitted only once and regular items must be submitted as an order, each recurring profile must be submitted separately.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

I have tried before to scope out how to add more than one recurring profile to your cart, or add it with other items and believe me - it's really not worth the hassle.

Comment: i need to add recurring profile and simple product to cart as like bundled product . how can i do this in magento is there any possible to do this .